# Saving a tiff file with Bitmap.Save() creates a file with tenfold size?

Tags: c#, bitmap, tiff

I was asking myself, why the size of my original tiff is increasing **(from 992KB to 9,42 MB)**, when i save it with Bitmap.Save(). The question came up, because i currently work with tiffs, modifiy them and so on.

I saw two differencen between the files (besides the file size).

1. The compression.
   The originalTiff has no compression displayed in its details.
   The savedTiff has LZW compression.
2. The photometric interpretation. The originalTiffs photometric interpretation is YCbCR. The savedTiffs is RGB.

Is one of these properties the cause of the tenfold size increase?

This is the code i use:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\PJ.ITAMS\Deskto\originalTiff.tif");
bmp.Save(@"C:\Users\PJ.ITAMS\Desktop\savedTiff.tif",ImageFormat.Tiff);
bmp.Dispose();
```

If anything is unclear or i gave too little information i'm sorry and give you everything you ask for!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depending on the number of bits used for YCbCR: yes, it may greatly reduce file size because for each pixel you will have less bits devoted to color. Imagine RGB 888 (8 bit for each component) compared to YCbCR 844 (just for example). It means that you save one byte for each pixel.

Comment: If possible, worth attaching that original tiff.

Comment: @Evk http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/713661/originalTiff.tif  This file sharing site seemed to be the best/quickest choice right now. I hope it's okay.

Comment: @SgtMeowBlank except this one wants my email for some reason :)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Okay, the i will try to convert/save the bitmap with YCbCR and look how the size is changing.

Comment: @Evk Yeah i saw it to ^^ If this is a problem, then i choose another , or you suggest a file sharing site. :)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Sorry for the inconvenience, but do you know how to convert RGB to YCbCR in C#? I already tried with the image flags of the bitmap, but they only got a setter. Another option i thought of, was using the color palette of the bitmap, but i don't find there a working solution too.

Comment: I **think** that the only color space supported by GDI+ driver is RGB (and few compression schemes). But honestly I'm not sure about this.

Comment: Hm okay, then i do more research and/or try to find a workaround. Thanks for your information!

Answer (score 1):

The file size is larger Because you didn't specify a compression.
This way the file is saved as an uncompressed tif.

The save Function of the Bitmap class is also overloaded with a function that takes EncoderParameters as an argument. This is how you control compression.

you can find more information here:
[MSDN documentation of Image.Save (The Bitmap Class implements Image)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ytz20d80(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It's possible but (quoting from question): _"The compression. The originalTiff has no compression displayed in its details. The savedTiff has LZW compression."_ (in OP's case it's the other way)